# How to add <?xml-stylesheet to QDomDocument?

Tags: xslt, qt4, qdomdocument

I've created an xml document with QDomDocument class. Now I want to add a link to a style-sheet. Is it possible with QDomDocument?

I couldn't identify a method for it in the documentation.

Comment: That link is a processing instruction, with the W3C DOM you would use `document.insertBefore(document.createProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type='text/xsl' href='sheet.xsl'"), document.documentElement)`. No idea whether that works with your DOM implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the API documentation it looks like `document.insertBefore(document.createProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type='text/xsl' href='sheet.xsl'"), document.documentElement())` should do.

Comment: Ok great, it did! I thought xsl link should be dedicated a special method.